# PINMUX register in AM335

Tags: beagleboneblack, device-tree

I just want to change pin mode for certain pins in AM335 device tree. I made those changes in device tree but I am not seeing those changes in pincntl class. I added below block in am33xx_pinmux node.

```
&am33xx_pinmux {

    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&clkout2_pin>;

    led_button_test: led_button_test {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x844, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN |MUX_MODE7)/*gpmc_a1.gpio1_17 */ 
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x9a4, PIN_INPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7)     /* MCASP0_FSR 
            .gpio3_19 */ 
                >;
        };
}
```

DO I need to add anything else?

Comment: What is the version of the kernel-image you are using ?

Comment: Linux kernel version 4.8.13

Comment: Or maybe you want to do this too at the boot time ?

Answer (score 0):

The pinmux value for 0x844 and 0x9a4 wont be set unless there is someone actually using this node led_button_test.

```
 led_button_test: led_button_test {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x844, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN |MUX_MODE7)/*gpmc_a1.gpio1_17 */ 
            AM33XX_IOPAD(0x9a4, PIN_INPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7)     /* MCASP0_FSR 
            .gpio3_19 */ 
                >;
        };
```

So if you add some node which refers led_button_test for example as below:

```
example@0 {
    ...
    ...
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&led_button_test>;
};
```